# iOS unable to access protected react routes

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-router, auth0

After successfully authenticating with Auth0, I am unable to navigate to protected routes (instead, I am redirected back to `LandingPage` - No errors appear in console logs).

This issue only occurs on iOS (both for Chrome and Safari!)

- I am using `BrowserRouter`
- `chrome://inspect` yields no logs
- Hosted on Netflify (includes a `/public/_redirects` file)
- When I inspect the URL on iOS after authenticating I notice the URL includes `https://my-domain/?code=...&state=...` however no redirection occurs.
- When I manually go to `https://my-domain/dashboard` after authenticating, I am still unable to navigate to this route.
- In Auth0, I have allowed callback URLs: `http://my-site.com` and `http://my-site.com/dashboard`.

Routes file:

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth0, withAuthenticationRequired } from '@auth0/auth0-react'
import { Header, UnauthenticatedHeader, Loader } from '../components'
import { LandingPage, Dashboard, Profile } from '../pages'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'

const ProtectedComponent = ({ component, ...propsForComponent}) => {
  const Cp = withAuthenticationRequired(component);
  return <Container>
    <Cp {...propsForComponent} />
  </Container>
};

export default function Router() {

  const { isLoading, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <Routes>
      {
        (isLoading) 
        ? <Route path="*" element={<Loader />} /> 
        : <Route path="/" element={
            <>
              {
                (!isAuthenticated)
                ? <UnauthenticatedHeader />
                : <Header />
              }
              <Outlet />
            </>
          }>
            {/* Unauthenticated */}
            <Route index element={<LandingPage />} />
            
            {/* Authenticated */}
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<ProtectedComponent component={Dashboard} />} />
            <Route path="profile" element={<ProtectedComponent component={Profile} />} />
          </Route>
      }

      {/* catch-all */}
      <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

function NoMatch() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Page not found.</h2>
      <p>
        <Link to="/">Go to the home page</Link>
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My `LandingPage` component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react'

export default function LandingPage() {
  const { loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return navigate('dashboard')
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, navigate])

  return (
    <div>
      <a onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>
        Create FREE Account
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What is the landing page? This seems to be an odd route protection implementation, but I suspect that's due to how `auth0` chose to make it work on their end. Where is any redirect occurring? Is that something that's wrapped up in the `withAuthenticationRequired` HOC?

Comment: @DrewReese Yep, the redirect occurs in the HOC:
When you wrap your components in this Higher Order Component and an anonymous user visits your component they will be redirected to the login page and returned to the page they were redirected from after login.
LandingPage is just a simple div with some links.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the code you've shared. Are you saying this code works well for Android and web browser and is only an iOS issue? What debugging have you tried? You may likely need to connect an iphone (physical or simulated) to the Safari browser on a Mac to see any logs. Are there any errors at all, anywhere?

Comment: Works on Android without issues.
The issue is only present on iOS devices: iPhone and iPad tested so far (both Safari and Chrome)
I have inspected chrome://inspect and there are no errors whatsoever.
I'm going to try hosting locally using ngrok to rule out any issues with Netlify.
TODO: source a mac.

Comment: @Blair, what is your callback URL? Please, hide the sensitive information.

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli I am redirecting back to the current page, which redirects the user if they are logged in via: `navigate('dashboard')`.

Comment: You still haven't really provided enough context for anyone to provide meaningful help. Does this `withAuthenticationRequired` HOC do something significantly different than the `useAuth0` hook? Does the `withAuthenticationRequired` HOC need to be used? Can you try creating a more conventional protected route component that checks the authenticated status and renders the redirect for unauthenticated users? Your code doesn't look drastically different than the `react-router-dom@6` examples in the repo. have you checked for any known issues?

Comment: @DrewReese The routing was as red-herring in my case. I stripped back my app and deduced that a call to `getAccessTokenSilently()` was causing  the problem, which lead me to a known-issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deduction, this turned out to be a known issue in Safari and unrelated to `react-router`. The issue also affected Chrome in my case:
https://auth0.com/docs/troubleshoot/authentication-issues/renew-tokens-when-using-safari

Elsewhere in my app (in an Apollo wrapper), I was fetching an access token by using `getAccessTokenSilently()`.

To verify the issue on iOS:

- Settings > Chrome: enable "Allow Cross-Website Tracking";
  or
- Settings > Safari: disable "Prevent Cross-Site Tracking"

In the browser, clear cache / and reload. Silent auth should now work.

The fix:

```
    <Auth0Provider
      ...
      useRefreshTokens={true} // <-- Added this
    >
```

In Auth0 settings:

- Enable `Refresh Token Rotation`
- Set `Reuse Interval` of 3.